# Returning the value of a class member pointer variable using 'this' pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, this

My scenario is , I want to return the value of class member variable `m_ptr` using `this` pointer.

What I have tried is ,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test{
    int *m_ptr;
    
    
    public:
        Test():m_ptr(nullptr){
            cout<<"Def constr"<<endl;
        }
        
        Test(int *a):m_ptr(a){
            cout<<"Para constr"<<endl;
        }
        
        ~Test(){
            cout<<"Destr "<<endl;
            delete m_ptr;
        }
        
        int getValue(){
            return *m_ptr;
        }

};

int main(){
    
    Test obj(new int(34));
    cout<<"Value -"<<obj.getValue()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The console output is

```
Para constr
Value -34
Destr
```

This is fine.

What I am trying to do now is ,

I want to modify the `getValue` function to return the value of pointer variable `m_ptr` using `this` pointer like below . (only writing the `getValue` function)

```
int getValue(){
    return this->(*m_ptr);
}
```

But this throws the error as,

> [Error] expected unqualified-id before '(' token

I am beginner in this c++ and  I am not understanding the actual reason for this error. It will be helpful to explain what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Use `return *(this->m_ptr);` instead

Comment: You maybe want `return *(this->m_ptr);`, but it's not clear why you want to put `this` into it when it's working fine to begin with. The right hand side of `this->` has to be an actual member of the class `Test`. So you can do `*(this->m_ptr)` which accesses `m_ptr` and then dereferences, but not `this->(*m_ptr)` which would imply that `(*m_ptr)` itself is somehow a member of `Test`.

Comment: @NathanPierson: That's an amazing explanation. As you told , I can start working with initial scenario but I was just curious about this one .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indirection operator is in the wrong place. `this->m_ptr` would be correct to access the member, and to indirect through that pointer, you put the indirection operator on the left side:

```
return *this->m_ptr;
```

Comment: Another good option . +1 for this. But could you please explain how this `*this` works here. For the another option @Nathan has explained. It would be nice to know about this also. Because `this` will print the address of the current object and if so then what is `*this` ?

Comment: @VishnuCS In fact there is no `*this` because of the language's [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) rules. Because `->` binds more tightly than `*`, the expression is equivalent to `*(this->m_ptr);` not `(*this)->m_ptr;`